# Condition on function which would satisfy specific inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $L(t,s)  \in M_+(R^2)$ and $t,s \in R_+$.
Consider
$$
A(t,v)=\int_0^{1/v}L(1/t,s)ds,
$$
which is decreasing with $v$ and increasing with $t$.

What conditions on $L$ would guarantee that $A(t,v)\leq A(t,u)+A(u,v)$ with $v<u<t$?

So far I have been able to find that, if $L=1/t+s$ the condition would work. I am looking for more general answer.

Comment: What's $M_+(R^2)$?

Comment: Its a positively measurable set on $R^2$. For example, Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditions you have given assure the inequality, assume that $r < s< t$. If $0 < s < t$, then $0 < \frac{1}{t} < \frac{1}{s}$ so that $$\begin{align*}A(r,s) = \int_0^\frac{1}{s} L\Big(\frac{1}{r},\xi\Big)d\xi &= \int_0^{\frac{1}{t}}L\Big(\frac{1}{r},\xi\Big)d\xi  + \int_{\frac{1}{t}}^{\frac{1}{s}}L\Big(\frac{1}{r},\xi\Big)d\xi \\
&= A(r,t) + \int_{\frac{1}{t}}^{\frac{1}{s}} L\Big(\frac{1}{r},\xi\Big)d\xi\\ 
 A(r,t) &= A(r,s) - \int_{\frac{1}{t}}^{\frac{1}{s}}L\Big(\frac{1}{r},\xi\Big)d\xi  \leq A(r,s) \\
&\leq A(r,s) + A(s,t)
\end{align*}$$
Above we used that since $L(\cdot,\cdot)\in M_+(\mathbb{R}^2)$ then $-\int_{\frac{1}{t}}^{\frac{1}{s}}L\Big(\frac{1}{r},\xi\Big)d\xi \leq 0$. Similarly $A(\cdot, \cdot) \geq 0$ by the same condition on $L$. So the conditions given always ensure this result.